# Check for new message during script

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a bot, which would solve a maze of another bot. To move through a maze, you must use commands (like '!wall','!step', etc.) and to each command you get a response. So far, I have created a bot, which responds to those messages well, but I have problem with turning, because at that point, my bot starts sending two messages at once. It's because it still uses a message, that is one response old and thus creates a gap where my bot inserts another message.

Here is the code which I am using right now.

```
async def on_message(self, ctx):
        message_input = ctx.content
        message_content = " ".join(line.strip() for line in message_input.splitlines())
        time.sleep(1)
        #MOVEMENT
        #keep right
        await ctx.channel.send("!turn right")
        await ctx.channel.send("!wall")
        async def on_message(self, ctx):
            message_input = ctx.content
            message_content = " ".join(line.strip() for line in message_input.splitlines())
            #move if no wall in front
            if message_content == f"__**Wall**__ You can move forward.":
                return await ctx.channel.send("!step")
            #if wall is in front, turn forward again and check for walls
            if message_content == f"__**Wall**__ There is a wall in front of you.":
                await ctx.channel.send("!turn left")
                await ctx.channel.send("!wall")
                async def on_message(self, ctx):
                    message_input = ctx.content
                    message_content = " ".join(line.strip() for line in message_input.splitlines())
                    #if wall is still in front of me, turn around and go back
                    if message_content == f"__**Wall**__ There is a wall in front of you.":
                        await ctx.channel.send("!turn right")
                        await ctx.channel.send("!turn right")
                        await ctx.channel.send("!step")
                    #if no wall is in front of me, keep going forward
                    else:
                        await ctx.channel.send("!step")
```

Here, I have tried using another `async def on_message(self, ctx)` to update a message but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what should I do?

Comment: Why do you have 3 nested `on_message`s? Look into `commands` and `wait_for`.

Comment: @stijndcl wow, that's exactly what I have been looking for :D. Sorry I am new to this. Thank you for your advice.